# Chain "then" request in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two call in my controller which using service and return some data. My second call is depend on result of a first one. How can i chain two call and get data from second only when first one is resolve?

```
InviteFriendsCodeService.getLeagueCode().then( (resp) => {
  ctrl.invitationCode = resp.data.data.leagues[0].code;

  return false;


});

InviteFriendsCodeService.getInviteLink().then( (resp) => {

 ctrl.recruitCode = resp.data.data.code;
 ctrl.invitationLink = `${window.location.origin}/registration/?recruit=${ctrl.recruitCode}&league=${ctrl.invitationCode}`

 return false;

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both of your calls are independent to each other (because you're not using the response of first to fire-off the second).

So you can fire them off simultaneously and assign controller members when they both resolve. Like this:

```
Promise.all([
  InviteFriendsCodeService.getLeagueCode(),
  InviteFriendsCodeService.getInviteLink()
]).then(function(resp) {
  ctrl.invitationCode = resp[0].data.data.leagues[0].code;
  ctrl.recruitCode = resp[1].data.data.code;
  ctrl.invitationLink = `${window.location.origin}/registration/?recruit=${ctrl.recruitCode}&league=${ctrl.invitationCode}`
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you return another promise from a `then` function, the original promise will resolve with whatever the returned promise resolves to, allowing you to chain the two:

```
InviteFriendsCodeService.getLeagueCode()
  .then( (resp) => {
    ctrl.invitationCode = resp.data.data.leagues[0].code;
    return InviteFriendsCodeService.getInviteLink();
  }).then( (resp) => {
   ctrl.recruitCode = resp.data.data.code;
   ctrl.invitationLink = `${window.location.origin}/registration/?recruit=${ctrl.recruitCode}&league=${ctrl.invitationCode}`
 return false;
  });
```

Comment: thanks for answer, it's working, but approved one fits better for my task

Answer (score 0):

Write your second call in the then of first promise

```js
InviteFriendsCodeService.getLeagueCode().then((resp) => {
 ctrl.invitationCode = resp.data.data.leagues[0].code;
 InviteFriendsCodeService.getInviteLink().then((resp) => {
  ctrl.recruitCode = resp.data.data.code;
  ctrl.invitationLink = `${window.location.origin}/registration/?recruit=${ctrl.recruitCode}&league=${ctrl.invitationCode}`
  return false;
 });
 return false;
});
```